# Git permissions when executed from PHP in a Plesk environment

Tags: php, git, apache, plesk

I want to execute Git commands (`git pull`, `git status`) from within a PHP application in a virtual host managed by Plesk (Linux).

Since the git repository was setup by a vhosts system user, PHP scripts with Git commands (e.g. exec(`git pull`)) executed by Apache run in permission problems.

What file permissions should the local Git repository have to be modified by the system user as well as Apache running PHP scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You should have an ssh keys and in this way you don't have to worry about permissions since it will be done over SSH.

**[Here](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/)** is a list of different ways to share your code.
Click on the desired option and it will display the content of what needs to be done.

Comment: This is ok to manage Git permissions. But how to define file permissions and ownership?

Comment: What is your central repository? GitHub? bitbucket etc

Comment: I'm on bitbucket. But this should make no difference for local file permissions under Plesk.

Comment: Yep, ask to give you instruction on how to add ssh keys if you don't know how. If you will use ssh keys it has nothing to do with the user. the ssh handshake is done via the keys regardless the user. simply use the git protocol and it should work

Comment: Here is the doc on how to set it up: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Comment: My question goes to local file permissions in Plesk/linux, not to communication issues with the Git server.

Comment: Still, use ssh key and you will not have to worry about the permissions, place the ssh keys under your root/plesk user `~/.ssh` folder, clone the project and thats it.

Comment: I don't use the root user but a vhost specific user. And that's what raises permission issues sice Apache runs as www-data user.

Comment: you can set it for the root user (ssh keys) or for the vhost user, just make sure that the certificates are there.

Comment: The Git communication works perfect when using from the command line. But when Apache tries to execute a Git command in a PHP script there are not sufficient permissions to modify files in the local repo after thy got fetched from the remote Git repo.

Comment: OK, so the problem is not with git itself. you will need to set the `chmod/chown` of the folder to the apache user

Comment: I tried that but then command line access doesn't work anymore. Aditionally changing owner and group will conflict tasks executed by Plesk (e.g from file manager). And setting file permisssions to 777 is not option for security reasons.

Comment: you dont need 777 - you can add the user to a specific unix group or Cgroup.

Answer (score 0):

PHP scripts working under Apache user only if "apache module" is used as PHP handler on domain.

Just switch PHP handler from apache module to FastCGI or PHP-FPM:

[image: Plesk PHP handler FastCGI / PHP-FPM]

Comment: Apache runs PHP scripts with www-data user and www-data group, but on the command line the vhost user has a different user name. also the group is different. That means when git tries to update files (e.g. git pull) it fails due to permission problems. And setting all files to 777 is no solution.

Comment: Think you miss the answer :) Just change php handler to fastcgi.